# I need to display data form API in tabular form in wix

Tags: dynamic, velo

In my website i have to show data in tabular form which I am getting from API. I successfully integrated API and I am getting response from that API but the problem is I don't know how to show it in a tabular form in Wix.

I tried dynamically adding HTML code in script file but it is not working. Please let me know if there is a way I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your data in a table element using the [rows](https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/draft/$w.Table.html#rows) property.

Comment: Tell me how to create a table in a wix with id table or myTable

Comment: @AyjazSayed, Go to the add menu on the left side of the editor, select Lists & Grids, and scroll down to the bottom section. There are a number of table designs to choose from.

Comment: Thanks, @Sam I successfully created a table and inserted data but now the issue is by default I am getting three rows which I don't want.

Comment: @AyjazSayed, sounds like you need to play with the table layout settings.